# File path returns 'null' for a given location and filename

Tags: java

Can somebody please tell me where I am wrong in the code.I am trying to search for a particular file named `filename` in a directory path and trying to return the `filepath` but it is always returning `null`.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public String walk( String path, String filename ) {
String filePath = null;
    File root = new File( path );
    File[] list = root.listFiles();

    for ( File f : list ) {
        if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
            walk( f.getAbsolutePath(),filename );
           }
        else if (f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(filename)){
            System.out.println( "File:" +f.getAbsolutePath() );
            filePath= f.getAbsolutePath();
           if(filePath.endsWith(memberPath)){
               System.out.println( "Found: Should exit");
               break;
           }
        }
     }
    System.out.println( "OUT of for:"  );
    return filePath;
}
```

it prints
     OUT of for:

```
 OUT of for:    

 File:d:\IM\EclipseWorkspaces\runtime-EclipseApplication\SIT\So\mmm\aaa\xxx.c

Should exit

OUT of for:

OUT of for:
```

I dont understand why it still goes back to the loop

EDIT: UPDATE:

I have found another way. please correct if there is something wrong  :declare filePath as a static variable

```
    public static void walk( String path, String filename ) {

    File root = new File( path );
    File[] list = root.listFiles();

    for ( File f : list ) {
       if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
            walk( f.getAbsolutePath(),filename );
           }
        else if (f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(filename) && f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(memberPath)){
             System.out.println( "Should exit");
             filePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
             break;
     }
       }

}
```

Comment: Where does `memberPath` come from? Why do you have the line `if(filePath.endsWith(memberPath))` at all?

Comment: the if (filePath.endsWith(memberPath)) can be the problem - because only when this is satisfied the loop is breaked, oh their is another problem i dont see this is a recursive call please  add to if (f.isDirectory() {filePath = walk(f.getAbsolutePath(), filename)})

Comment: it is a static variable with the relative path of the file

Comment: Note: In case you are using Java SE 7, it's recommended to use the new NIO File API where possible: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the part with `memberPath`. Change your code to look like this:

```
public String walk(String path, String filename) {
    String filePath = null;
    File root = new File(path);
    File[] list = root.listFiles();

    for (File f : list) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            walk(f.getAbsolutePath(), filename);
        } else if (f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(filename)) {
            System.out.println("File:" + f.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("Found: Should exit");
            filePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
            break;
        }
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need the `memberPath` variable? Do you understand what your own code does?

Comment: @user1688404 It was not meant as an insult. The question remains: think about why you need the `memberPath` variable. Where is it declared and where is it set? What is the purpose of the `memberPath` variable?

Comment: :( that's an insult..anyways..:) the PATH in the method is d:\IM\EclipseWorkspaces\runtime-EclipseApplication\SIT and FILENAME is xxx.h. memberPath comes from another local text file which gives me a relative path of a file ' \Software\mmm\aaa\xxx.h'. what i want to know is that if the found xxx.h is the one with the relative path. it could happen that xxx.h could be there in different paths inside PATH

Comment: @user1688404 Why didn't you explain that earlier, instead of complaining about insults?

Comment: @Jesper.i didnt complain...it was a mistake that it appeared twice .. i was trying to edit, but it didnt allow me to edit that.. sorry from my part.

Comment: i have edited the orginal post. I changed the method a bit. Can you please see if there are any flaws with this implementation

Answer (score 1):

Return the file path as soon as it is found:

```
if(filePath.endsWith(memberPath))
{
    return filePath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String walk(String path, String filename) {
String filePath = null;
File root = new File(path);
File[] list = root.listFiles();

for (File f : list) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        // store the filePath 
        filePath = walk(f.getAbsolutePath(), filename);    
    } else if (f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(filename) && f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(memberPath)) {
        System.out.println("File:" + f.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("Found: Should exit");
        filePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        break;
    }
  if (filePath != null) {
    break;
  }
}
return filePath;
```

}

Edited: added f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(memberPath)

Comment: no luck..:( but i have found another way. please correct if there is something wrong. updated in teh original post